# Add section title to each line using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, perl, vim

I have a text file in the following format

```
[Section1]
property1 = value1
property2 = value2

[Section2]
property1 = value1
property2 = value2
```

An example

```
[Section foo]
foo = 1
bar = "whatever"
```

Is there any way I can add the section title to each line using regex like so

```
Section1: property1 = value1
Section1: property2 = value2

Section2: property1 = value1
Section2: property2 = value2
```

**Update**

I didn't include programming languages or tools so here is a list of possibilities

1. JavaScript
2. Perl
3. VIM

Open to any other suggestions including non regex.

Comment: Using what tools, programming language, OS?

Comment: No, this is not something that can be done with only regexes.  Regular expressions are not some magic wand that can fix any problem that relates to strings.

Comment: I understand that it isn't a magic wand but if one is not at expert level then it is difficult to assess what is possible and what is not. Hence why I asked the question here :) If it turns out it is not possible so be it.

Comment: Why do you specify "using regex like so"? You have already said what result you want, why restrict the method? That sounds like an arbitrary restriction to me. Is your question about solving your problem, or about regexes?

Comment: Yes. Maybe I restricted possible answers by including regex. I could have come up with a solution using perl without regex. However, I suppose it was just out of interest to see if anyone knew a clever way of doing it. Off course if others agree I can change the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.  First you're going to have to capture the following regex

```
\[(Section\d+)\]\n(.+?\n)|(?:.*?\n)\[Section\d+\]
```

which should capture your section label, and all of the lines that you want to apply it to.  after that, it should be simple stirng concatination

**Regexplanation**

```
()     : a capturing group  
(?:..) : non-capturing group  
\d+    : 1 or more digits  
.+?\n  : 1 or more characters and newline(the '?' means it's non-greedy)  
.*?\n  : 0 or more characters and newline
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I think this is the closest answer to what I am actually asking even though many of the other solutions also work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Vim solution — simply open the file and run this command:

```
:g/^\[.*\]$/ s/^\[// | s/\]$/:/ | d | ,/\n$/ normal PJ
```

This selects the section heading lines, transforms each one into the desired form for prefixing the other lines in that section, deletes the heading line, and inserts it at the start of all the other lines in the section.

In detail:

- `:g//` selects the lines in the file that match the pattern and applies the following commands to each of them. In this case the pattern matches lines which begin `[` and end `]`.
- The first `:s///` removes the opening `[` and the second one changes the closing `]` into a `:`. It isn't necessary to add a trailing space, because joining the lines (see below) will do that.
- The `|`s separate multiple `:` commands, allowing several actions under the scope of the initial `:g//`.
- The `:d` deletes the line. This also stores it in a register from where it can be pasted. And it means that the ‘current’ line is now the first property line in the section.
- The prefix needs adding to all the lines in the section. `,` defines a range.
- The start of the range is the current line. That's the default, so there doesn't need to be anything before the `,`.
- The last line in the range is the one just before a blank line (or the end of the file). This requires examining the line after the one being considered for the end of the range. The `\n` does that, matching the line-break character at the end of a line and taking the pattern past it, on to the next line (if there is one). If that point is the end of a line, matched with `$`, then there must be a blank line following (because there's another end-of-line immediately after the `\n`) or we're at the end of the file.
- So `,/\n$/` defines the range of lines that need prefixing.
- `:put!` will insert the recently deleted line above the current one, making that just-inserted line then be the current one, and then `:join` will join that line with the following one, inserting a space between them. We want to do that for each of the lines in the range.
- But `:put` doesn't take a range, just a line. Normally to apply a command to each line in a range one would use `:g//`. But here we're already inside a `:g//` command, and they can't be nested.
- Fortunately `:normal` applies the specified normal-mode keystrokes to each line in a range. Pressing `P` in normal normal mode is the same as the `:put!` command, and `J` is the same as `:join`.
- So `,/\n$/ normal PJ` says that for each line from the current to the one before a blank line (or the end of the file) paste the recently deleted prefix above it and then join the existing line on to the end of the prefix.
- `:normal` can't be followed by another command, because any `|` would be interpreted as a normal-mode keystroke rather than a command separator. So in general using `:normal` in a command sequence requires wrapping it in `:exe`. But in this case `:normal` is the last thing we want to do, so it can just be left as it is at the end of the command.
- Once the above has transformed the first section, Vim moves on to the second section heading that it matched with the `:g//` and does it again.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a one-liner:

```
perl -F"\n" -00 -anwE '$h = shift @F; 
                       $h =~ s/^\[|\]$//g; 
                       say "$h: $_" for @F; 
                       say $/;' paragraph.txt
```

With this code we use paragraph mode to read blocks of lines from the file, autosplit each block on newlines, then take off the first line of the block, clean it up and use it as our header in the resulting print (`say`).

- `-00` set input record separator to the empty string to enable paragraph mode, i.e. reading up until the next double newline.
- `-a` auto split each line of input into `@F`
- `-F` switch allows us to set a newline as delimiter for the autosplit
- `-E` like `-e` but enables features, like `say`

The code looks like this in script form:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

$/ = "";                      # paragraph mode, read until "\n\n"
use feature 'say';            # enable 'say'
while (<>) {                 
    my @F = split /\n/;       
    my $h = shift @F;         
    $h =~ s/^\[|\]$//g;       # clean up lines
    say "$h: $_" for @F;      
    say $/;                   # print paragraph ending 
}
```

Comment: You've accidentally added an additional right paren after `while`.

Comment: @Kenosis Thanks, leftover from the deparsed code which I cleaned up. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

This regex capture the values in group :

```
\[(?<Section>.*?)\]\r\n(?<p1>property\d)\s=\s(?<v1>value\d)\r\n(?<p2>property\d)\s=\s(?<v2>value\d)
```

This one is used for replace the preceding capture :

```
${Section} : ${p1} = ${v1} 
${Section} : ${p2} = ${v2}
```

The results in Expresso tool is :

> Section1 : property1 = value1
>   Section1 : property2 = value2
>
> Section2 : property1 = value1
>   Section2 : property2 = value2

This must be optimized to make it generic

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -n -wE 'if (/^\[(\w+)\]$/) { $section = $1; } else { s/^(?=\S)/$section: /; print; }' yourfile.txt
```

The `-n` makes `perl` process each line of the file at a time. If the line looks like a section heading then it stores the section name for future use. Otherwise it prepends the previously stored section name to any line which starts with a printable character, then prints the line.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option that's run from the command line using `perl <scriptName> <dataFile>`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $section;
while (<>) {
    if (/^\[(Section[^\]]*)\]$/) {
        $section = $1;
        next;
    }
    print /\S/ ? "$section: $_" : $_;
}
```